# Cannot resolve method "findItem(int)"

Tags: android

I just tried this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item.findItem(R.id.action_search),
                    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    System.out.println("expand");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    System.out.println("collapse");
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But it shows me an error, saying :

> Cannot resolve method "findItem(int)"

I checked on [android developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29) and the method seems to be valid the way I use it.
Does anyone know why it doesn't work ?
Thanks

Comment: `findItem()` exists for `Menu`, not for `MenuItem`.

Comment: you are trying to find a `MenuItem` from a `MenuItem` which makes no sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs says it should be called Menu

```
item.findItem(R.id.action_search) // Here item is MenuItem not Menu
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    System.out.println("expand");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    System.out.println("collapse");
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```